# Meaning of "ever so" phrase

Tags: meaning, phrases

I recently listend to an audio book and this sentence stuck in my head

> he put her on the cot gently and ever so gently

mainly because I heard it a few more times (not the exact sentence, but the "ever so" phrase) until the end of the book. What does it exactly mean? I can guess that it emphasizes *slowly* in this case, like he did it really slow?

Comment: correct.  Typically used for soft, slow, gentle, etc.  You'd be less likely to see "ever so hard/strong/fast/etc" - though you do on occasion (and it has the same meaning of emphasizing the adverb).

Comment: "With the currency ever so strong against the US dollar Brazilians are..." ;)

Comment: @Doc: That's an interesting idea, but [the evidence from NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ever+so+hard%2Cever+so+soft&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cever%20so%20hard%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cever%20so%20soft%3B%2Cc0) suggests to me that if anything, the relative dominance of **so hard** over **so soft** actually becomes *more* pronounced when they're preceded by **ever**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Wow, you're right.  I find that surprising - I very rarely hear/see the "ever so..." used with the more aggressive words.  Must be reading the wrong stuff.  That said, compare "ever so hard" to "ever so gently"; gently has completely overtaken hard since the early 1900's.

Comment: @FumbleFingers see [this NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ever+so+quickly%2Cever+so+hard%2C+ever+so+fast%2C+ever+so+slowly%2Cever+so+gently%2Cever+so+soft&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cever%20so%20quickly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cever%20so%20hard%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cever%20so%20fast%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cever%20so%20slowly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cever%20so%20gently%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cever%20so%20soft%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Doc: Actually, comparing *so xxx* and *ever so xxx* doesn't mean much, since they're not "alternatives". The [bottom line](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=very+hard%2Cever+so+hard%2Cvery+soft%2Cever+so+soft%2Cvery+softly%2Cever+so+softly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvery%20hard%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cever%20so%20hard%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvery%20soft%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cever%20so%20soft%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvery%20softly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cever%20so%20softly%3B%2Cc0) is that ***ever so xxx*** always "flatlines" against ***very xxx***.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ever so](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ever+so) is an intensifier (usually) for adjectives, meaning **very**

> Life is made of ever so many partings welded together. - Charles Dickens
>
> Be it ever so humble, there's no place like home.
>
> Of course, it also shows that Peter is ever so old, but he is really always the same age, so that does not matter in the least. - J.M. Barrie (Peter Pan)

Comment: Is there some rule of thumb when to use it instead of very? It seams to me that it mostly finds its place in books or poems.

Comment: That's correct, it is more common in writing, and is considered to be somewhat formal. Thank you *ever so much* is still heard.

Comment: @Ondrej: As Susan says, *ever so [adjective]* may be seen as rather formal. But it's also worth noting that [it's a declining usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+ever+so&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20ever%20so%3B%2Cc0). If you want a quick and easy rule of thumb for when to use *ever so* instead of *very*, the best answer is probably *"**Never!**"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Maybe if I am to write a book. Which won't happen :)